# "Test events were not received" when run tests using gradle 6.2.2

Tags: gradle, testing, junit5

I have a Java multimodule project and when I run console command "./gradlew :tests:test" or using IDEA "test -p tests" or ":tests:test" i have the message "Test events were not received". Running tests via IDEA and jUnit5 works just fine.
I used --info to see what is going on.

My project:
Java **1.8**;
Junit **5**;
Gradle **6.2.2**

I found that my tasks :tests:testClass is skipped as it has no action. I thought i may have some problems with test classpath. But it looks like it's ok.

My **build.gradle.kts**:

```
configure<QualityExtension> {
  configDir= "$gradleScriptDir/quality"
  sourceSets = listOf(
    project.sourceSets.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME),
    project.sourceSets.getByName(SourceSet.TEST_SOURCE_SET_NAME))
}
```

My **junitPlatformBuild**:

```
configure(allprojects) {
group = "ru.*"
version = version

tasks.withType(Test::class) {
    ignoreFailures = true

    useJUnitPlatform {

        systemProperty("web.webdriver.remote", "true")

        if ("true" == System.getProperty("parallel")) {
            systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", "true")
            systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default", "concurrent")
        }

        includeTags = (System.getProperty("includeTags") ?: "none").split(',').toSet()
        excludeTags = (System.getProperty("excludeTags") ?: "WIP,debug").split(',').toSet()
        (System.getProperty("params") ?: "")
                .split(',')
                .forEach { p ->
                    systemProperty(
                            p.split(':').get(0).trim(),
                            p.split(':').getOrElse(1) { "" }.trim())
                }
    }
}
```

}

So, SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME = "main" and SourceSet.TEST_SOURCE_SET_NAME = "test".
My workDir is "*tests/src/test/java*". Looks like SourceSet should be fine. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the `includeTags` system property for your call, you effectively do `includeTags = "none"` which then probably causes indeed no test to be executed.